# Multiple labels and select elements but one does not display

Tags: html

Apologies for this but I've obviously been staring at my monitor too long...

When I run the following code in jsfiddle then only the first label/select and last label/select elements are displayed but not the middle one and I cannot see why

```
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">

        <label id="a1" >City</label>
        <select id="cityDropDownList"  />

        <label id="a2" >Property</label>
        <select id="propertyDropDownList"  />

        <label id="a3" >Room Type</label>
        <select id="roomTypeDropDownList"  />

    </form>
</body>
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Do you have a link to jsfiddle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrong using [SELECT TAG](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_select.asp)

```
<select>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

Becuse of you didn't close select tag, next tags were displayed improperly.

Comment: This certainly is true and solves the problem on jsfiddle. However for a good answer I'd also wish you would give any form of explanation for this behavior. In the end two of three invalid select tags were shown correctly...

Comment: Ok so that solved my issue and I'll now put forward myself for numpty of the year. Thanks for the quick response.

Answer (score 0):

You asked for why **it doesn't select the middle one.**

Actually the selector of jquery works as it parsed html by tag.

It works for the first and third as it matches the "first and second" tag as single HTML SELECT TAG AS THERE IS NOT ENDING TAG for first tag. So third SELECT also works ... and fourth tag WILL not work :)

So write like this:

```
<select id="first_select"></select>
<select id="second_select"></select>
```